# The instance of entity type 'x' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'a', 'b'} is already being tracked

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I got the error in the title while editing relational table between many-to-many relationship. It will not let duplicate on table, so I try to remove rows and then create new one but it didn't work.

```
public void Update(ThermoformProduct entity, int[] thermoformCategoryIds)
{
    using (var context = new ShopContext())
    {
        var product = context.ThermoformProducts                  
            .Include(i => i.ThermoformProductCategories)                
            .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductId == entity.ProductId);            

        if (product != null)
        {           
            product.Code = entity.Code;
            product.Culture = entity.Culture;
            product.Renk = entity.Renk;
            product.UstGenislik = entity.UstGenislik;
            product.UstCap = entity.UstCap;
            product.AltCap = entity.AltCap;
            product.TbCap = entity.TbCap;
            product.Yukseklik = entity.Yukseklik;
            product.Hacim = entity.Hacim;
            product.TamHacim = entity.TamHacim;
            product.Baski = entity.Baski;
            product.SosisIciAdet = entity.SosisIciAdet;
            product.KoliIciAdet = entity.KoliIciAdet;
            product.ImageUrl = entity.ImageUrl;

            product.ThermoformProductCategories.RemoveAll(s=>s.ProductId == product.ProductId);

            product.ThermoformProductCategories = thermoformCategoryIds.Select(catid =>  new ThermoformProductCategory()
            {
                ProductId = product.ProductId,
                ThermoformProduct = product,
                CategoryId = catid,
                ThermoformCategory = context.ThermoformCategories.Where(i => i.CategoryId == catid).FirstOrDefault()

            }).ToList();

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF cannot track two different instance of an entity type with same primary key. You have included the related `ThermoformProductCategory` entities, so they are being tracked by the context. When you remove them, they are cleared from the `ThermoformProductCategories` property of that product, but they are not removed from the context, and are still being tracked. Finally when you create the new list of `ThermoformProductCategory`, some of the new ones' primary key are matching the previous ones' (which already exist in the context)

Since you are creating the entire list again, you don't need to fetch the related entities in the first place. Simply assign a new list and EF will replace the entire list of related entities -

```
var product = context.ThermoformProducts.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductId == entity.ProductId);
if (product != null)
{       
    // set all the properties

    product.ThermoformProductCategories = thermoformCategoryIds.Select(catid =>  new ThermoformProductCategory()
    {
        ProductId = product.ProductId,
        CategoryId = catid
    }).ToList();

    context.SaveChanges();     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. The filter is redundant - the `ThermoformProductCategories` navigation property should already be filtered.

```
product.ThermoformProductCategories.RemoveAll(s=>s.ProductId == product.ProductId);
```

instead do this:

```
product.ThermoformProductCategories.RemoveAll(); // Or .Clear()
```

2. Don't set navigation properties in this case, just the foreign key values - this should resolve your issue:

Instead of:

```
product.ThermoformProductCategories = thermoformCategoryIds.Select(catid =>  new ThermoformProductCategory()
{
    ProductId = product.ProductId,
    ThermoformProduct = product,
    CategoryId = catid,
    ThermoformCategory = context.ThermoformCategories.Where(i => i.CategoryId == catid).FirstOrDefault()

}).ToList();
```

Do:

```
product.ThermoformProductCategories = thermoformCategoryIds.Select(catid =>  new ThermoformProductCategory()
{
    ProductId = product.ProductId, // Even this might be redundant since you're adding to the product navigation property list.
    CategoryId = catid
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

both answers was solution here is my final form if anyone gets trouble

```
 public void Update(ThermoformProduct entity, int[] thermoformCategoryIds)
    {
        using (var context = new ShopContext())
        {
            var product = context.ThermoformProducts                  
                .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductId == entity.ProductId);            

            if (product != null)
            {
                
                product.Code = entity.Code;
                product.Culture = entity.Culture;
                product.Renk = entity.Renk;
                product.UstGenislik = entity.UstGenislik;
                product.UstCap = entity.UstCap;
                product.AltCap = entity.AltCap;
                product.TbCap = entity.TbCap;
                product.Yukseklik = entity.Yukseklik;
                product.Hacim = entity.Hacim;
                product.TamHacim = entity.TamHacim;
                product.Baski = entity.Baski;
                product.SosisIciAdet = entity.SosisIciAdet;
                product.KoliIciAdet = entity.KoliIciAdet;
                product.ImageUrl = entity.ImageUrl;
             
                var cmd = "delete from ThermoformProductCategory where ProductId=@p0";
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(cmd, product.ProductId);    
                
                product.ThermoformProductCategories = thermoformCategoryIds.Select(catid =>  new ThermoformProductCategory()
                {
                    ProductId = product.ProductId,                       
                    CategoryId = catid,
                    ThermoformCategory = context.ThermoformCategories.Where(i => i.CategoryId == catid).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList();

                context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;                   
                context.SaveChanges();                   
            }
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to use the Raw SQL command if you let EntityFramework do it's job (of tracking changes) by ```include```ing the ThermoformProductCategories  when you load the product and then manipulating the loaded list instead. Running raw SQL like this goes behind EFs back and makes changes to the datastore that EF doesn't know about which could cause problems in the future.

Comment: @Lacutah after solved instance error i got trouble from duplicate raw error and productcategory.removeall and .clear methods didnt work

Comment: It'll work fine if you INCLUDE the categories, then EF will track changes made to the list: ```var product = context.ThermoformProducts.Include(p => p.ThermoformProductCategories)                 
                .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductId == entity.ProductId);``` - this is a feature of EF Core 5.0+

Comment: (Sometimes version matters, LOL)